# CLIPS EnvAssertString API-function slow performance

Tags: c++, clips

I'm trying to develop an expert-system which is capable of managing a real-time data flow. During the coding procedure I found a delay in operation which varied from 3 to almost 20 milliseconds and this is totally inappropriate for the project. The application profiling showed that the problem resided in `EnvAssertString` function, whilst `EnvRun` did not produce any delay. I tried to temporaily disable garbage collection before `EnvAssertString`, but it didn't help. The function in question is performed between 10 and 50 times in a row during the processing of a single block of data and the blocks are arriving at a rate of approx. 15 blocks per second.

How can I fix this? Is there any chance of speeding the process up? Is CLIPS at all suitable for a real-time response like that (sevaral calls in a row to `EnvAssertString` shouldn't take longer than 1 ms)?

Comment: If you have rules, remove them and see how that effects performance. Pattern matching occurs when you assert a fact, so that is most likely where time is being spent.

Comment: Really? `EnvAssertString` triggers pattern-matching? Is there a way of disabling it? And what about `EnvRun` then?

Comment: Pattern matching is performed whenever a fact is asserted whether that's through the EnvAssertString API, the command prompt or from the actions of a rule. You can't disable that.

Comment: Doesn't it mean then that if I assert a fact the rules should fire automatically? That doesn't ever happen until I call `EnvRun`.

Comment: Facts are compared with the rules constraints during their assertion. `EnvRun` executes the consequent of the rules which all constraints have been satisfied.

Comment: @noxdafox, thank you -- it has become much clearer to me! Is there any way of profiling it by tracing pattern-mathcing? Is it possible to figure out which rules cause processing to take such a great deal of time?

Comment: @GaryRiley, I have one more question: is `test(...)` faster than predicate constraints used alongside deftemplate slots to evalute during pattern-matching process?

Comment: @JamesFrezz Predicate constraints are performed in the pattern network if all the referenced variables have been bound in the enclosing pattern. If a referenced variable is bound in a different pattern, then the constraint is evaluated in the join network. A test CE is always evaluated in the join network regardless of where the variables are bound. Generally if an expression is not computationally expensive, it is more efficient to evaluate it in the pattern network because if the expression fails the fact/instance does not have to be propagated through the join network.

Comment: You can check the `Profiling Commands` and `Debugging Commands` chapters in the [Basic Programming Guide](http://clipsrules.sourceforge.net/documentation/v630/bpg.pdf) reference manual.